# Gauge covariant derivative of an adjoint action: $\psi(x) \to g \psi(x) g^{-1}$, instead of a left action $\psi(x)\to e^{iq\theta(x)} \psi(x)$

Tags: derivatives, covariance, gauge-theory

In the case where the transformation on $\psi$ is applied from the left:

$$
\psi(x)\to e^{-iq\theta(x)}\psi(x).
$$

The gauge covariant derivative is

$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu - iqA_\mu \tag{1}
$$

and the field is given as follows:

$$
F_{\mu\nu}=[D_\mu,D_\nu]. \tag{2}
$$

---

My question is; what are the equivalents to equation (1) and (2) if we have an adjoint action such as this

$$
\psi(x) \to g(x)\psi(x)g^{-1}(x)
$$

where $g(x)$ could be arbitrary general linear transformations for instance. Does the use of a adjoint action transformation significantly changes (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that
$
\partial_\mu (g\psi g^{-1})
= g \left( \partial_\mu \psi + [ g^{-1}(\partial_\mu g), \psi ] \right) g^{-1}
.$
Therefore, we set
$D_\mu\psi = \partial_\mu\psi - [iq A_\mu, \psi].$
Then,
$$
D_\mu(g\psi g^{-1}) 
= g \left( \partial_\mu g - [iq g^{-1}A_\mu g-g^{-1}(\partial_\mu g),\psi] \right) g^{-1}
$$
so $A_\mu$ should transform to $g^{-1}A_\mu g-\frac{1}{iq}g^{-1}(\partial_\mu g).$

I'm no expert on this, but I think that $F_{\mu\nu}=[D_\mu,D_\nu]$ is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an “index free” description.

Let A be a connection on a principal $G$-bundle $P$, and $\rho:G\to\text{GL}(V)$ be a representation. Then $\rho$ induces a representation (its derivative) which we also denote $\rho:\mathfrak g \to \text{End}(V)$.

If $\psi$ is a section of an associated vector bundle $E:=P\times_{G,\rho}V$, then the covariant derivative $\nabla^A$ associated to $A$ is given by
$$
\nabla^A \psi = d\psi + \rho(A)\psi
$$
So for a straightforward left action, $A$ will act similarly.
For the Adjoint action
$$
\nabla^A \psi = d\psi + [A,\psi]
$$

For curvature,
$$
\rho(F_{X,Y})\psi = [\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]\psi-\nabla_{[X,Y]}\psi
$$
(For coordinate derivatives $\partial_\mu$ you can ignore the last term.)
This implies the defining formula for $F$ is the same, but if written out in matrices, say, $F$ will act differently on fields $\psi$ of different representations.